How to use git filter-repo to rewrite history in a Gitlab repository that uses git LFS?
I have a private Gitlab repository that I want to make public, but some of the people who have worked on it don't want their names/Gitlab accounts to be visible there. I wanted to scrub their names, then, and I heard about git filter-repo as the "state of the art" for doing it, so to speak.
As I understood it, I have to update my local copy and then push it to a new repo, so that any comments/merge requests/etc they made to the Gitlab project (as opposed to just the repo's commit history itself) would also be gone. However, I'm using git LFS—the project contains a number of image files, Photoshop files, etc—and I have enough of them stored that they go beyond the free storage available on Gitlab and I needed to buy extra.
How do I deal with that? It seems like trying to push to a new repo won't work, because LFS tries to reupload the files to the new repo rather than just having references to the old files. Will I need to buy extra storage for the new repo and then upload? How do I do it?
(Also, it's possible I was doing it all wrong; I wasn't 100% comfortable with my understanding of how filter-repo works. I'd appreciate a more step-by-step answer with the right commands and so on if possible!)

You could try pushing them to a new branch in the existing repo and (if everything went well) delete the old branch as well as the issues/merge request of people you don't want to be visible.

Wouldn't their personal pages still show their activity on the Gitlab page if I just made the original project public?

I don't know much about Gitlab but if you delete all of their issues/merge requests and also all branches they have commits in (don't delete the new filtered branch), I think it shouldn't show up but you'd have to test that.
